# Is CD4 an alkane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons, isotope

Can $\ce{CD4}$ or $\ce{CT4}$ be considered an alkane?

I know that an [alkane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkane) is $\ce{C_nH_p}$ where $p = 2n + 2$. An alkane is considered a "hydro"carbon, i.e., a compound containing purely carbon and "hydrogen" only. However, "hydrogen" has mainly three [isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_hydrogen):
protium ($\ce{^1_1H}$ or $\ce{H}$), deuterium ($\ce{^2_1H}$ or $\ce{D}$) and tritium ($\ce{^3_1H}$ or $\ce{T}$).

Thus, in general, can $\ce{C_nH_xD_yT_z}$ be considered an alkane/ene/yne, where $x, y, z \in \{ 0, 1,\dots,2n + 2 / 2n /2n-2 \}$ and $x + y + z = 2n + 2 / 2n /2n-2$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $2/2n/2n$ ?

Comment: @Maurice Correlate it with **alkane/ene/yne** : **2n+2/2n/2n-2**.

Comment: You are asking a question about CD4 before introducing D. This is bad.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are still alkanes and they are named *deuterated/tritiated* alkanes. It's correct that alkanes are primarily considered hydrocarbons but if the hydrogen is replaced with deuterium/tritium, the names are also changed and this replacement is not a theoretical one. Practically this is possible ([ACS Catal. **2018**, 8, 3, 2296–2312](https://doi.org/10.1021/acscatal.7b04201)).

Comment: Can we call them D/T-substituted alkane?

Comment: @CHEMUMAN  Is $\ce{H2^{18}O}$ water? Yes, it is. $\ce{CD4}$ is nothing else but $\ce{C^{2}H4}$. Do not let convention $\ce{^{2}H}$ being written as $\ce{D}$ confuse you. H in CH4 means hydrogen, not protium.

Comment: @Poutnik What do you mean is that $\ce{CH_4}$ is actually a mixture of various compounds of isotopes of carbon & isotopes of hydrogen(e.g.:  $\ce{^14_6C _1^3H_4}$ is also methane), isn't it?

Comment: @CHEMUMAN Yes, I do. There is nowhere said methane is a compound of carbon-12 and hydrogen-1.  Molecules differing just by isotopic composition are called [Isotopologues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopologue) // Hydrogen is exception just formally, having dedicated symbols for its isotopes, as they have relatively biggest differences due the biggest relative mass differences.  So H, D, T as hydrogen-1,  hydrogen-2 and hydrogen-3 formally look like 3 different elements, while being just one.

Comment: @Poutnik The link provided by you really helped. Thanks.